# System UI has stopped working Oneplus 2 running Paranoid Android 6.01

Tags: system-error, oneplus-two

I flashed the PA 6.01 ROM a few days ago and every time I reboot and the device turns on and an error pops up saying System UI has stopped and when I press OK it just starts the bootanimation again and after the animation has finished the error pops up again and I click OK and the process just keeps repeating in a loop. The first time this happened, I went to my recovery wiped everything but internal storage reflashed the rom, gapps bank ARM64 and SUPER SU. then just reboot. The error has popped up again and again even after doing the wipe and reflash many times do any of you guys know how to fix it? Because I really like PA the battery life it give is just amazing and I find the floating peek feature very very useful. And if any of you guys cant figure it out can you please tell me how to flash oxygen os?

Answer (score 0):

Hard reset the phone by pressing the volume button and the power and hold it down.
You will loose your data
click on the below youtube link to see how to do this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l6Y1-2uUyO4